# Remove class of elements with same class incrementally without repeating code

Tags: jquery

I am creating an animation where I am incrementally removing a class from elements with the same class. My code works, however I was hoping there was a way of writing this code without repeating myself. How would you do this?

```
window.onload = function() {
    var rectangle = jQuery('.rectangle');
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        jQuery(rectangle[0]).removeClass('rectangle-transparent');
    }, 000);
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        jQuery(rectangle[1]).removeClass('rectangle-transparent');
    }, 100);
     setTimeout(function(){ 
        jQuery(rectangle[2]).removeClass('rectangle-transparent');
    }, 200);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write one function and call it..

```
window.onload = function() {
    function myRemove(index){
         var rectangle = jQuery('.rectangle');
         jQuery(rectangle[index]).removeClass('rectangle-transparent');
    }
    
    setTimeout(function(){ myRemove(0) }, 000);
    setTimeout(function(){ myRemove(1) }, 100);
    setTimeout(function(){ myRemove(2) }, 200);
};
```

Comment: this is a good idea, however, the timeout function dose not work.

Comment: Thank you, this uses significantly less code, and works well.